# I am trying use custom annotation in java . But not able to get the annotation in

Tags: java, annotations

Bellow is my Custom Annotation:-

```
@Documented
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface InputBox{

    int width() default 20;
    int length() default 20;
    String placeholder();
    String title();
    String friendlyName();
    String name();

}
```

Here I am using the annotation  :-

```
public class Table {

    private long id;

    @InputBox(width = 25 ,length = 25, placeholder = "" , title = "" , friendlyName = "" , name = "")
    public String name;

    @InputBox(length = 10,placeholder = "",title = ""  , friendlyName = "" , name = "")
    private int age;}}
```

Parser :- Here I am passing className to get the annotation details but not able to get the annotation and  isAnnotationPresent method giving null pointer exception -

```
public JSONArray getFormMetaData(String className) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class cl = null;
        try{
            cl = Class.forName(className);
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

        for(Field f: cl.getDeclaredFields())
        {
            if( f.getDeclaredAnnotations().length >0 ){
                if(f.isAnnotationPresent(InputBox.class)){
                    JSONObject obj = AnnotationProcessor.processInputBoxAnnotation(f);
                    obj.put("type","text");
                    jsonArray.add(obj);
                }}}
```

When I am accessing the same annotation in a static main method I am getting proper results . Ex :-

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {


    Table.class.getDeclaredFields()[1].getDeclaredAnnotations();

}
```

}

But when I am trying to get results calling through api I am not getting any annotation.

Comment: So you get a nullpointer in the if condition?

Comment: Yes  f.isAnnotationPresent(InputBox.class) is giving null pointer exception .

Comment: Seems like your @InputBox annotation is not on the runtime classpath. How did you add it to the classpath?

Comment: Did you paste your actual code? What server in what version are you using? What jre in what version is the server using?

Answer (score 0):

I just make main method in your Table Class to test , its work fine refer below code.

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

public class Table {

    private long id;

    @InputBox(width = 25, length = 25, placeholder = "", title = "", friendlyName = "", name = "")
    public String name;

    @InputBox(length = 10, placeholder = "", title = "", friendlyName = "", name = "")
    private int age;

    public void testAnnotation(String className) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {
        Class cl = null;
        try {
            cl = Class.forName(className);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        for (Field f : cl.getDeclaredFields()) {
            if (f.getDeclaredAnnotations().length > 0) {
                if (f.isAnnotationPresent(InputBox.class)) {
                    System.out.println("annotationPresent");
                }
            }
        }



    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException {

        new Table().testAnnotation(Table.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes , As I mentioned if I am calling from static main method everyting is working fine. But when I am  deploying the same code on server and calling through api then getting null pointer exception in  --    if(f.isAnnotationPresent(InputBox.class))   and f.getDeclaredAnnotations() is giving null.